# Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer does not see XUnit dnx traits

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit, xunit.net, dnx

The Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer does not recognize my test traits.

When I add this to a test in a DNX project:

```
[Trait("Category", "Test")]
```

the test still shows up in the Test Explorer under the No Traits group (when grouping tests by Traits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is already logged as an issue:

[VS 2015 Bugs - Traits and Project Grouping in Test Explorer #485](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/485)

Comment: Yup, It is an open issue with VS2015. I am having same trouble here.

Comment: The xUnit Team says this was fixed in beta5. Today I posted a comment on xunit @ github since I still see the issue with RC1. The response was that it is an issue for the "ASP.NET Tooling Team".  Does  anybody know if the xUnit traits show up for anybody? Or is it 100% not working?
[TheLinkToTheComment](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/530)

Comment: I'm running VS2015 14.0.25425.01 Update 3 and it's still not categorizing by trait. Oh but I'm not using dnx...