# xUnit + VS2015, does group by Traits work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, xunit.net

I'm using xUnit with VS2015. Some codes are decorated by [Trait("Category", "C1")]. However, in the test explorer, it always shows 'no traits' when using group by traits. I tried to put the decoration at both class and method level.

I searched. It seems it was a bug in year 2015: [Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer does not see XUnit dnx traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258618/visual-studio-2015-test-explorer-does-not-see-xunit-dnx-traits)

Is this fixed now? Does it work for anyone? or, still a bug? Anyone can confirm this?
xUnit: 2.1.0
VS: 14.0.25123.00 update 2.
.Net 4.6.01055

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 Update 3, doesn't fix it, waiting for the next update I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Is working for me.
Maybe you'll need to clean and rebuild the solution.
I defined

```
public enum TypeOfTests
{
    UnitTests,
    IntegrationTests,
}
```

This is kind of what I'm doing at class level:

```
[Trait(nameof(TypeOfTests), nameof(TypeOfTests.IntegrationTests))]
```

or

```
[Trait(nameof(TypeOfTests), nameof(TypeOfTests.UnitTests))]
```

You can use strings instead, but I think this way is cleaner.
You'll see traits working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it worked for me when i added a Trait to class level but not when i only had traits on methods.