# VS2015 Test Explorer doesn't detect traits in AspNetCore project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, mstest, asp.net-core-testhost

For some reason, Test Explorer in my VS2015 Community Edition doesn't detect traits in AspNetCore test project. I am using mstest testRunner.

All test methods go into "No Traits" category despite proper TestCategory annotations.

1. I have tried both single annotation and several ones (which actually
   I am trying to capitalize on).
2. I have trying assigning them to
   test class and test method.
3. I am using the latest nuget packages
   for test-related dependencies:

   1. "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.1.2-preview",
   2. "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.1.11",
   3. "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0",

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258618/visual-studio-2015-test-explorer-does-not-see-xunit-dnx-traits) here on StackOverflow. Not sure yours can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: The question you have mentioned is about xUnit and it's [Trait] annotation, and I am using mstest v2 that logically should be supported better from MS side.

I was basing my efforts on this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer/

Comment: PS: So in my case "doing wrong" was using VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the latest version (1.1.11) of the MSTest test framework and adapter:

Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/

Adapter: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/

Also, please use VS2017 (this was not supported via VS2015).

Let me know if you still see the issue.

Comment: to the benefit of other .NET testing frameworks developers, where can I find more info on how to pass traits to VS Test Explorer? E.g. if I look at [Test.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0-preview2/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Testing.Abstractions/Test.cs) there's no hint on that. Same thing for [communication protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/test-protocol). Thanks!

Comment: @pvlakshm, As I have clearly stated above, I am already using 1.1.11 for TestFramerwork. Now I have added a proper dependency on TestAdapter, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @superjos, I have posted a link to a nice article above. But that doesn't work in my particular case ((. I also want to mention that the annotation is different depending on what testing library (MSTest, NUnit, xUnit) you're using.

Comment: Konstantin thanks for clarifying, although I'm actually contributing to a testing library and I cannot find any pointer to where traits should be passed, while there were docs available for former version of VS test platform model and .NET framework Test Adapters. That's why I was asking directly @pvlakshm if he got any reference "from inside"

Comment: Ha-ha, a great idea to switch to EAP made by MS ) Thank you for your efforts though, and I will accept the answer. Though, I am very disappointed if it's the only option, because I'd like to stick to 2015 till 2017 come live (and it's better if the SP1 will be there as well).